# Onto linear mapping between families of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

This problem is used to prove soomething about the orbits of solutions for systems of differential equations;

It states that there is an onto linear mapping between the families of curves ${y=c_1x^m}$ and ${y=c_2x^n}$ iff $m=n$ or $m=1/n$.

Any hints would be great.the one direction is obvious.

Comment: How about just substituting? Note that $0$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Sorry i did not get you it somehow looks very simple but i can't get my head around it...

Answer (score 0):

Since both graphs of $y=c_1x^m$ and $y=c_2x^n$ pass through the origin, you should only consider maps of the form $y=cx$ and $x=cy$ with $c\ne0$.

So you need to find $m$ and $n$ so that each graph of $y=c_1x^m$ with $c_1\in\mathbb R$ goes to the graph of $y=c_2x^n$ for some $c_2\in\mathbb R$ (which may depend on $c_1$). When $x$ is replaced by $cx$ we obtain
$$
y=c_1(cx)^m=c_1c^mx^m
$$
and if $c_1c^mx^m=c_2x^n$ for all $x$, then of course $m=n$ (and you get some relation between $c_1$ and $c_2$ that does not matter for the problem).

Similarly, When $y$ is replaced by $cy$ we obtain $m=1/n$.